# Conditionally set property in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to set a property conditionally in maven depending on whether it is a snapshot build or not. The pseudocode looks as follows

```
if ${project.version} ends with "-SNAPSHOT"     
then
   deployFileUrl = ${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}
else
   deployFileUrl = ${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}
```

How can I implement this in maven?

I tried it with the build-helper-maven-plugin as follows

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>regex-properties</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>regex-properties</goal>
                </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <regexPropertySettings>
                            <regexPropertySetting>
                                <name>deployFileUrl</name>
                                <value>${project.version}</value>
                                <regex>.*-SNAPSHOT</regex>
                                <replacement>${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}</replacement>
                                <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                            </regexPropertySetting>
                        </regexPropertySettings>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem with this approach is that I can not implement the else-condition.

Comment: [Build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) are your answer.

Comment: yup. @biziclop is right sadly. Maven isn't like ant. doing logic was never really the idea. If you want to do scripting in Maven, try using the maven ant plugin.

Comment: @biziclop then I need a way to activate the corresponding profile based on if it is a snapshot or not...if else condition still exists...

Comment: @RenéWinkler No, because you'll have two profiles. Profile `A` activates if the build is a snapshot, and profile `B` activates if `A` is inactive.

Comment: The whole thing is superflous cause that will be handled by Maven automatically. If you have a number which is a release maven will use the release repository and if the version is a SNAPSHOT version maven uses the snapshot repository.

Comment: @biziclop I tried it but without success. I guess you can not use the build-helper-maven-plugin in the plugin section that sets a property that is already used in the beginning of the pom to activate a profile...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I ended up using the maven-antrun-plugin as follows

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <configuration>
                <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
                <target>
                    <condition property="isSnapshot">
                        <contains string="${project.version}" substring="SNAPSHOT" />
                    </condition>
                    <condition property="deployFileUrl"
                        value="${project.distributionManagement.snapshotRepository.url}">
                        <isset property="isSnapshot" />
                    </condition>
                    <!-- Properties in ant are immutable, so the following assignments 
                        will only take place if deployFileUrl is not yet set. -->
                    <property name="deployFileUrl"
                        value="${project.distributionManagement.repository.url}" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 8):

To set the property to two different values depends on a snapshot build (or another condition) you can use the following:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- sets the only.when.is.snapshot.used property to true
                        if SNAPSHOT was used, to the project version otherwise -->
                        <id>build-helper-regex-is-snapshot-used</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>regex-property</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>dockerTag</name>
                            <value>${project.version} dev latest</value>
                            <regex>(?=.*SNAPSHOT).*(dev).*|.*(latest).*</regex>
                            <replacement>$1$2</replacement>
                            <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

It set `dockerTag` property to `dev` or `latest` depends on build type.

If you wants to change property values is should change it in two places.For example for `true` and `false` use
`<value>${project.version} true false</value>` and `<regex>(?=.*SNAPSHOT).*(true).*|.*(false).*</regex>`.

Answer (score 1):

The whole thing is superflous cause that will be handled by Maven automatically. If you have a version number which is a release version like `1.2.3` maven will use the release repository and if the version is a SNAPSHOT version like '1.2.3-SNAPSHOT` maven uses the snapshot repository.

Comment: I knew there would be someone telling me that. Unfortunately, I did not figure out how to maven let manage this for my specific case. The problem is that I am building an obfuscated jar of a project with the proguard-maven-plugin. This plugin generates an additional jar which I have to install and deploy subsequently with the corresponding plugins. I need to specify a url in the maven-deploy-plugin, i.e. either the snapshot or release repository url.

Comment: This sounds your setup is wrong...the plugin will attach that appropriate jar to the project and during the deploy phase it will automatically transfered to the remote repository...without a real pom file it's hard to tell where the problem is...